# Draw a specific number line

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

dI would like to draw the following number line where N is just a fixed number

and B1 is the set {1,...,N} etc.

[image]

Although i searched and found somes codes displaying similar lines using tikz

i couldnt adjust the proper modifications. Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.2,font=\footnotesize]
\draw (0,0) -- (12,0);
%
\foreach\m/\n in {0/1,3/N,4/N+1,7/2N,8/2N+1,11/3N}
    {\node[scale=.7] at (\m,0) {$|$};
     \node[below,yshift=-5pt] at (\m,0) {$\n$};}
%
\path
    node[above] at (1.5,0) {$B_1$}
    node[above] at (5.5,0) {$B_2$}
    node[above] at (9.5,0) {$B_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `3/N`, I think,  `6/2N`?